# SAP ui 5 router error when initiating the sap.f.router

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I got an error when initiating sap ui program, please help

manifest.json

```json
"sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "latihan1.view.App",
        "type": "XML"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {},
            "sap.f": {},
            "sap.ui.layout": {}
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "fullWidth": true
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
```

and index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>latihan1</title>

        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, sap.f, sap.ui.layout"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"latihan1": ""}'>
        </script>
```

and component.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "latihan1/model/models",
    "sap/f/library"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models, library) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("latihan1.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */
        init: function() {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
            
            // enable routing
            this.getRouter().initialize();

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
```

[image]

The library already loaded

[image]

Comment: Can you post your complete manifest.json? I guess essential information is missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The specified class for router or targets 'sap.f.routing.Router' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143810/the-specified-class-for-router-or-targets-sap-f-routing-router-is-undefined)

Comment: the sapui is 1.52

Comment: @samin Do you get the same result if you launch the app with `src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"` in `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `sap/f/library` inside the dependencies of your Component. Can you try that? Having them in the manifest inside the `libs` is enough. You don't even need those inside the index file as well.

However what seems be missing in your `manifest.json` file is the router class under `sap.ui5` section.

```
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router"
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I tried it but still not working, the same error still happening

Comment: Can you please share the ‘routing’ section of the manifest.json file?